# What are the qualities of a good field day site?

Tags: field-day, location

What are the qualities of a good field day site? Specifically what do you or your clubs look for or use as criteria for site selection?

Comment: I'd vote to keep open as this is a common question for those new to organizing a field day, and though not directly answerable, understanding that there is a list of concerns that can go into a successful FD site/experience IS responsive and helpful to the community.

Answer (score 2):

(Posted as an answer instead of a comment due to size)

---

In short, the current question ("What are the qualities of a good field day site? ") is unanswerable because:

Objectively, it depends on what the PEOPLE NEED who will be using the site. So really start with some questions:

- How many people does the site need to accommodate?
- What is the climate, and likely weather in the area?
- Do the people intend to operate 24x7?
- Will people need a place to sleep if rotating on/off?
- How many concurrent stations will satisfy the volume of people available to operate?
- Will the people generally be more interested in prioritizing points, the camping experience, the in-person social aspects, the operating aspects, the site setup/tear-down aspects, the publicity and recruitment aspects, the educational and equipment testing aspects, etc?
- What bands do the people intend to operate on?

Based on the answers to these and other questions, a "good" site will have markedly different definitions.

So while not necessarily a purely opinion based question, your team/club/personal definition of "good" needs to be explored and stated because currently there is no shared understanding of it.

---

I may delete this if OP updates question

Comment: This is a form of frame challenge; as such it's a legitimate answer of the form "you're not asking the right question."

Comment: Good answer, worth keeping anyway.

Comment: I'd say, we could improve the question by changing it from "what's a good field day like" to  "which criteria should I consider when designing a field day"; it wouldn't break the spirit of the original question too badly, give OP a useful answer, and remove the "this is really subjective" as an immediate concern.